# Uso de "¿el qué?" después de que alguien dijo algo a otra persona

Tags: gramática

En una película española llamada *Contratiempo* observé varias situaciones en las que después de que alguien dijo algo a otra persona, otra persona respondió con "¿el qué?":

> *-Voy a necesitar algo más.*
> *-¿**El qué**?*

> *-Yo no sabía lo que ahora sé y él todavía ignora.
>
> -¿**El qué**?*

Mis preguntas:

1. ¿Hubiera sido correcto si otra persona hubiera respondido solo con "¿qué?"?
2. ¿Podría haber otras variaciones en respuestas, como: "el cómo", "el quién", "el cuándo", etc.? Dependiendo de una oración anterior, por supuesto... o en estas ocasiones solo puede ser algo así (solo un ejemplo): "*-Lo hizo él. -¿Quién?*"

En relación con la segunda pregunta, en una serie de Netflix llamada *La Víctima Número Ocho* veo esta oración:

> *...Ahora es importante que te guste **el cómo***.

Es decir, no estoy seguro de que esto "el cómo" pertenezca a una misma regla como en caso de "¿El qué?". Pero quise dar un ejemplo.

Comment: ¿estás seguro que dicen "el qué" y no están diciendo "qué qué" ? En Colombia es muy frecuente preguntar "¿que qué?" para expresar sorpresa al escuchar algo poco creíble.

Comment: en España es común usar esta forma, @DGaleano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sobre *[qué](https://www.rae.es/dpd/qu%C3%A9)* dice el DPD que cuando aparece solo (o más bien, cuando debería aparecer solo), se le suele añadir el artículo:

> 1.1. Pronombre interrogativo o exclamativo, que, referido siempre a cosas, introduce enunciados interrogativos o exclamativos directos, y
> oraciones subordinadas interrogativas o exclamativas indirectas (...).
> **Puede constituir por sí solo un enunciado:
> «—¿Sabes una cosa? —¿Qué?» (Padilla Jardín [Cuba 1981]). En estos
> casos, es frecuente en el habla coloquial la anteposición del artículo
> *el*: «—Germán, esto no funciona. —¿El qué?» (Marsillach Ático [Esp.
> 1995]);** pero no es admisible en la lengua culta anteponer a este
> pronombre el artículo neutro *lo*: «—No sé, fue un instante, un
> relámpago; y en ese relámpago sentí de nuevo... —¿Lo qué?» (Mahieu
> Gallina [Arg. 1980]).

Mi impresión personal (esto ya no lo dice el DPD ni otra fuente que haya encontrado), este uso de *“¿el qué?”* es más común en España. En Argentina es bastante frecuente, en el registro informal, la otra opción que el DPD menciona como inadmisible: *“¿lo qué?”*. En cualquier caso creo que es mejor al escribir, salvo que sea para transmitir un tono coloquial, usar siempre el “¿qué?” sin agregados.

El otro asunto de “el cómo” es diferente. En este caso se está tratando la palabra interrogativa como un sustantivo. “El cómo” es “la manera o forma (en que algo ocurre), el medio (utilizado para hacer algo)”. “El cuándo” equivale a “el momento (adecuado o propicio para hacer algo, o en que algo sucede)”. “El porqué” es “la razón, el motivo”, y así.

Un ejemplo de uso sería, por ejemplo, hablando de un crimen: “Ya sabemos quién lo hizo y cuándo ocurrió. Ahora nos falta investigar **el cómo y el porqué**.” Nótese que *porqué* va escrito como una sola palabra cuando es un sustantivo.

La misma frase podría funcionar sin transformar los pronombres interrogativos en sustantivos, y sin colocarles artículo: “Ahora nos falta investigar **cómo y por qué**.”